# How do I print out a list of common factors for two numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I need to print out a list of common factors for two numbers

```
def print_nums(x, y):
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            print(i)
    for t in range(1, y + 1):
        if y % t == 0:
            print(t)


number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
number2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))

print("Common factors are: ".format(number, number2))
print_nums(number, number2)
```

It prints out both lists but not the common factors of each

Comment: You are finding factors, but where do you check if they are "common"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def print_nums(x, y):
    zet = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            #print(i)
            zet.append(i)
    for t in range(1, y + 1):
        if y % t == 0 and t in zet:
            print(t)


number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
number2 = int(input("Enter a second number: "))

print("Common factors are:")
print_nums(number, number2)
```

Example of running the code:

```
Enter a number: 24                                                                                                                                                                  
Enter a second number: 18                                                                                                                                                           
Common factors are:                                                                                                                                                                 
1                                                                                                                                                                                   
2                                                                                                                                                                                   
3                                                                                                                                                                                   
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code just prints factors, not common factors. You could loop over `x` and `y`'s common range and check if `i` is a factor of both:

```
def common_factors(x, y):
    for i in range(2, min(x, y)+1):  # 1 is trivial, so ignore it
        if x % i == 0 and y % i == 0:  # If x and y are both multiples of i
            yield i

print(list(common_factors(9, 12)))  # -> [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

basically same thought as the above solutions..but a nifty function to basically check for only items in the list which are non-unique..like the opposite of set...this returns common factors because they will occur more than once

```
from iteration_utilities import duplicates, unique_everseen

facs=[]

def print_nums(x, y, facs):
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            facs.append(i)
    for t in range(1, y + 1):
        if y % t == 0:
            facs.append(t)
    return list(unique_everseen(duplicates(facs)))
```