# There are two lists one is of factors and another of numbers I want a program to collect all the common factors out of the all factors as follows:

Tags: python-3.x

numbers = [4,6,8,10]
factors = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10]

following output is expected
common factors = [1,2]

There are two lists one is of factors and another of numbers I want a program to collect all the common factors out of the all factors as follows:

```
def factor12(nums):
    factors = []
    for index in range(len(nums)):
        for i in range(1,nums[index]+1):
            if nums[index]%i == 0:
                factors.append(i)
        all_factors = list(set(factors))
        print(all_factors)
nums = [4,6,8,10]
factor12(nums)
```

I have found out all facotors by above code only need to find out which are common out of them

Comment: Just to confirm - `common` factors are those can apply to all number in `numbers`?

Comment: yes the factor is common if it divides all the numbers in the list with zero remainder

Comment: Maybe this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780560/how-do-i-print-out-a-list-of-common-factors-for-two-numbers can help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print out a list of common factors for two numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780560/how-do-i-print-out-a-list-of-common-factors-for-two-numbers)

Comment: What have you tried? You haven't posted any code.

Comment: of course I can print the common factors of two or more numbers but the problem arises when we don't know for how many numbers we want to find the common factor. Here is my code to find common factors which is not giving desired output

Comment: @DanielHao  I have uploaded the code