# Finding common factors

Tags: python, list

So, if I am trying to find factors of a number I would use

```
def factors(x):
    l=[]
    for i in range(1,x+1):
      if x % i == 0:
        l.append(i)
```

But I am stuck with finding common factors if instead of a number for x it would be a list. Is there a way to find common factors of a list? I'm stuck

Comment: Perhaps this could help: [common factors for two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780560/how-do-i-print-out-a-list-of-common-factors-for-two-numbers)

Comment: You could: 1) use your factors to find the factors of each element in the list, and 2) generate the intersection of all the lists to obtain the common factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all`:

```py
def factors(lst):
    output = []
    for i in range(1, min(lst) + 1):
        if all(x % i == 0 for x in lst):
            output.append(i)
    return output

print(factors([12, 60, 72])) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12]
```

There might be more efficient ways; for example, you could use `math.gcd` instead of `min(lst)`, using the fact that every common divisor is a factor of the gcd. Also then you might as well count only up to the square root of the gcd instead of gcd, by noting that if x is a factor of gcd, then gcd//x is also a factor of gcd. But I'll leave this to the OP.